# Not a member of windows.forms.datagrid when switching to vb.net 2003 from 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid, visual-studio-2003

```
Dim sqlsyntax As String
        Dim result As String

        sqlsyntax = "INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_ID, OE_Category,OE_SubCategory, OE_Name, OE_User, OE_Brand, OE_Model, OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo, OE_PropertyNo, OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus, OE_Status, OE_Dept_Code,OE_Location_Code,OE_Remarks)" _
                 & "VALUES(@OE_ID,@OE_Category,@OE_SubCategory,@OE_Name,@OE_User,@OE_Brand,@OE_Model,@OE_Specs,@OE_SerialNo,@OE_PropertyNo,@OE_Static_IP,@OE_Vendor,@OE_PurchaseDate,@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear,@OE_WarrantyStatus,@OE_Status,@OE_Dept_Code,@OE_Location_Code,@OE_Remarks)"
        Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter

        adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlsyntax, sqlconn)

        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", SqlDbType.Char)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", SqlDbType.Char)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", SqlDbType.Int)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", SqlDbType.Char)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", SqlDbType.Char)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", SqlDbType.Char)
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar)


        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGrid1.VisibleRowCount - 1
            'adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpID.Text.Trim)
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = DataGrid1(i, 0).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(1).Value = DataGrid1(i, 1).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(2).Value = DataGrid1(i, 2).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(3).Value = DataGrid1(i, 3).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(4).Value = DataGrid1(i, 4).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(5).Value = DataGrid1(i, 5).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(6).Value = DataGrid1(i, 6).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(7).Value = DataGrid1(i, 7).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(8).Value = DataGrid1(i, 8).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(9).Value = DataGrid1(i, 9).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(10).Value = DataGrid1(i, 10).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(11).Value = DataGrid1(i, 11).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(12).Value = DataGrid1(i, 12).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(13).Value = DataGrid1(i, 13).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(14).Value = DataGrid1(i, 14).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(15).Value = DataGrid1(i, 15).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(16).Value = DataGrid1(i, 16).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(17).Value = DataGrid1(i, 17).GetType
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(18).Value = DataGrid1(i, 18).GetType

            result = adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("success fully added")
            adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Clear()
        Next
```

sir i revised the code to my following sql datas,

but returned error here

---->adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlsyntax, sqlconn)

ERROR:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EOEHR.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing in the code?

Comment: it has underlign in those codes and when i point the cursor it says somethign like rows is not a member of system.windows.forms.datagrid  i think this code is from a higher .net framework like vb.net 2008

Comment: DataGrid was replaced with DataGridView in 2.0 - DataGrid was left in for backwards compatibility.   There is no `Rows` property in DataGrid that I can see on MSDN.  Are you sure this code worked in 2008?

Comment: What is `grdFamily`?  The code is looping through the rows in `DataGrid1`...it's all rather confusing without some more context.

Comment: that was Im thinking that maybe that properties doesnt apply to datagrid. or vb.net2003  yes... but now im using vb.net 2003 my friend told me to use that code in order to insert records to sql

grdFamily is the datagrids name

Comment: I think you'll need to manipulate the underlying datasource and then rebind.  There doesn't appear to be any easy way to access the rows in a `DataGrid`.

Comment: can you provide me a sample code? even not the whole code just some ideas and ill be completing

Comment: Question: why are you moving to .NET 1.1? I cannot think of any reason to because .NET 2.0 is available for every OS that 1.1 is (even Windows 98).

Comment: By the way, you seem to be using C# code... (hence I updated my answer), but you don't have a C# tag? What language are you actually using?

Comment: @yu_ominae im using vb.net 2003 and sql server enterprise manager

Comment: @Dai sir because vb.net 2003 is the only .net that my company provides with license to use

Comment: @ivandinglasan Have you tried my answer? Did it get you anywhere? I am asking about the language, because the square brackets is C# syntax and will not compile in VB.Net...

Comment: @yu_ominae i didnt tried sir since you made it c# im sorry. i am using vb.net 2003 window forms datagrid

Comment: I converted it back to VB.Net and I think it should work now. more to the point. VB.Net will not take `[]` indexers, so your code would never have compiled. `[]` is C# syntax whilst VB.Net is `()`.

Comment: VS Express 2012 is available for free and should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know a `DataGrid` accesses the cells via indexing `MyDataGrid(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)`, just like an array. This allows you to get or set the value of the specified cell as an object which you then might or might not have to cast to the appropriate type.

`.Row(Index)` does not work for this control, neither does `.Column(Index)`, because there does not seem to be a collection exposed for either of those objects.

You could try changing your code to this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 'Get the table from the data source here and loop through that instead of just looping through the datagrid.
     adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(0).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpID.Text.Trim)
     adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(1).Value = grdFamily(i, 0).ToString()
     adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(2).Value = grdFamily(i, 1).ToString()
     adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(3).Value = grdFamily(i, 2).ToString()
     adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters(4).Value = grdFamily(i, 3).ToString()

     result = adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
     adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Clear()
```

Note I don't know what your datatypes are so I can't cast to the appropriate type in this sample.

UPDATE:

Just realised your code is in C#, whilst my answer was in VB.Net I updated to what I think is the correct C# syntax.

UPDATE2:

Not sure whether you are using C# or VB.NET you seem to have a mix of both, so updated answer to VB.Net again to reflect your question tag.

UPDATE 3:

OK, after doing some research what you are trying to do seems very complicated to do via the datagrid. You should really get VS2012 Express as @Dai suggested in the comments to your question.

In any case, if you are set on doing ti in .NET 1.1, you should really get hold of the `DataTable` you use to populate the datagrid and loop through that instead as it is MUCH simpler.
You can find many sources on the internet which will tell you how to do that.

I can't really provide you any more help than this. And to be honest I think this is as good an answer as you will get, unless somebody on here has some legacy code to hand or still remembers .Net 1.1 and is willing to rewrite your code for you.

Comment: still got error here in.

  For i As Integer = 0 To DataGrid1.Rows.Count - 1

underligned in 'datagrid1.rows'   note: not a member of the system.windows.forms.datagrid

Comment: Try it now. Since there is no `.Rows` property, I think you have to use VisibleRowCount (maybe...)

Comment: Actually I don't think this will do what you want. It seems to be VERY difficult to loop through a datagrid. Have a look at this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sailaja1/DataGridIteration11292005232850PM/DataGridIteration.aspx for example. It seems everybody recommends getting hold of the datasource of the datagrid and looping through that instead.

Comment: Honestly, this could be due to any number of things. I would suggest that you insert a break point just before you execute the command and look at all the parameters to make sure none of them are null. Since this is different from your original question about DataGrid, I would strongly suggest that you open a new question. You will get much more attention this way than by tagging on stuff to an old question.